# HTML Regex for domain name entry?

Tags: html, regex

Currently I have a form accepting domain names, so I need to preclude every special character & space except for `.` and `-` being entered.

my current code:

```
<input type="text" name="domain-name" placeholder="i.e. example.com" pattern="^(\d|\w)+$" class="form-field w-input" required id="domain-name">
```

Won't accept `.` or `-`

How can I change it so that it accepts `.` and `-`

Comment: Use `pattern="[\w.-]+"`, `^` and `$` are redundant in a pattern regex, `\w` matches digits by itself and just add `.` and `-` to the character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew worked a treat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern attribute should look like

```html
pattern="[\w.-]+"
```

**Details**

- The `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors are redundant in a *pattern* regex since the resulting RegExp object is compiled with the `^(?:` before and `)$` after the string pattern typed in the attribute value
- `\w` matches digits by itself, so `[\w\d]` = `\w`
- To match `.` or `-`, you need to put `\w` inside a character class, `[]`, and add `.` and `-` to this character class.